# How to trigger a Jenkins job from an approval of a Jira task

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jira, jira-plugin

I'm looking for a method to trigger remote Jenkins job based on Jira workflow status. The idea is to create a Jenkins job which is to be triggered based on Project Manager's approval.

When task gets approval status then Jenkins should trigger the job in project.

Note: I have created a webhook in Jira and configured required plugins in Jenkins.

Comment: Can you please list the plugins configured and clarify if configuration in  JIRA is modified ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I Understood correctly the question, you want to trigger the Jenkins Job when the Jira Item(task/ticket) is in particular state(e.g. Approved, In-progress).

You possibly need to have following Plugins:

1. [JIRA](https://plugins.jenkins.io/jira/)
2. [JIRA Pipeline Steps](https://plugins.jenkins.io/jira-steps/)
3. [JIRA Trigger Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/jira-trigger/)
4. [JIRA ext-plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/jira-ext/)

Before creating a job which will triggered based on Jira Item status, you need to have JIRA webhook integration.

[image]

The KEY* is the *TICKET PATTERN* required to integrate with Jenkins. Please find a link which explains a simple use case in [here](https://medium.com/@shrut_terminator/devops-usecase-jira-jenkins-integration-4051413446a9#:%7E:text=First%2C%20to%20enable%20Jira%20to,here%20in%20the%20Jenkins%20pipeline.&text=The%20%E2%80%9CSTATUS%E2%80%9D%20customfield%20of%20Jira%20matches%20%E2%80%9CIN%20PROGRESS%E2%80%9D.)

While creating jenkins job, you will get under category 'Build Trigger' additional option `'Build when issue is updated in JIRA'`.
After this be keen to update `JQL Filter` as per your need.